# If Shaken during your round, do you immediately roll to un-Shake?

Tags: savage-worlds, shaken

Say that I withdraw from melee during my round and, as a result of the opponent's free attack on me, I become Shaken. Or alternatively, I become Shaken due to Backlash from Arcane Background: Magic. Do I immediately roll to get out of Shaken? Or do I have to wait for my next round?

If the answer is "immediately", does that mean that you can roll to un-Shake multiple times in a round (e.g. roll to un-Shake at the start of your round, then get Shaken again, and then roll to un-Shake a second time during the same round)?

Comment: Haven't played the new shaken rules much, but excellent question...

Comment: @Phantomwhale I think this question would apply to both the current Shaken rules and the previous ones.

Comment: See this meta post -http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/shaken-tag-for-savage-worlds - for discussion about the Shaken tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you get to (*have* to) attempt to remove Shaken only when your action comes up.

> On their action<sup>[1]</sup>, a Shaken character must attempt to recover from being Shaken…
>   (*SW Deluxe*, p. 68; see my footnote below)

This is a precondition for taking the action, and there's no other circumstance that allows making this free roll. This means you can only attempt it once, and only when you're already Shaken when your turn arrives in the turn order. If you've become Shaken as a result of your own action or others' activity during your action, you don't get an immediate free attempt to remove it.

Of course, you *can* spend a Bennie at any time to remove Shaken.

> A player may spend a Benny at any time to remove his Shaken status. (*ibid.*)

---

1. <sup>Action here *almost* certainly refers to your turn to act rather than individual actions. It was more explicit in SWEX and SWR because the rule used the word “turn”, but it still appears to be the intended meaning in SWD because the *effect* of failing the attempt dictates that no actions at all may be taken other than free actions. That also means that even if it was per action when taking multi-actions, the second and later actions would never start. So one recovery roll holds for the entire turn, any way you read it, making the “they still mean ‘turn’ in *SWD*” reading simpler and so most plausible.</sup>

Comment: If it's a precondition for taking an action, does that mean you get multiple attempts if you declare that you want to take multiple actions? And how does that work with free actions?

Comment: That's interesting, as the rules a couple of years back (before the softening of the shaken rules) I'm fairly said they permitted shaken tests if shaken during your own turn (which would be overpowered in the new shaken rules)

Comment: @Phantomwhale It's been the same since at least Revised.

Comment: @Thunderforge Action here refers to your turn to act. It was more explicit in SWEX and SWR because it used the word “turn”, but it's still evidently the intent in SWD because the *effect* of failing the attempt dictates that no actions at all may be taken other than free actions, so even if it was per multi-action the rest would never start. So one roll holds for the entire turn any way you read it.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was thinking of when you'd only done movement (a free action) usually to withdraw (free attack) or attacking someone with First Strike.

This was all nicely clarified and updated by Client here: http://www.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=47857&p=434451&hilit=shaken+during+your+turn#p434451

Comment: Just to note that I've deleted my answer as I've found confirmation that the rule has been clarified so that you are only allowed to recover from Shaken with a Spirit roll once at the start of your turn